# Multiple LEDs & HC-SR04

Tags: sensors

I want to use a distance sensor like the HC-SR04 to power a stop light like parking sensor for my garage. I have seen a lot of tutorials on how to use the HC-SR04 to power a single LED and found the schematic below on how to control up to 14 LEDs by hooking them onto the 5v and using a transistor. I have added a box where I would hook the sensor in. My question is, would it work if I had the sensor hooked into the 5v as well. The plan is to have 3 sets of 14 LEDs and have one set on at any given time. I plan on using an Arduino Uno. [image: Schematic]

Comment: Thanks for all your help and encouragement. The link http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno says that there is a 5 v output straight from the board's voltage regulator. Is that not separate from the output pins?

Comment: If you power your Arduino through the Vin pin, the current limit will be given by the 5 V regulator. According to [it's datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCP1117-D.PDF), it's actually a power dissipation limit: the higher the Vin voltage, the lower the current limit (power = current × (Vin − 5 V)). Check the thermal pad size on your Arduino and refer to Fig. 21 (p. 8) of the datasheet.

Comment: Edgar, would I have enough current to run those LEDs and a distance sensor from the 5 v pin if I had a 9v 1A charger?

Comment: @user2969 If you hooked the power to VIN and GND, then that should be more than enough for the HC-SR04 and a handful of LEDs. On a side note, please ask another question if you have another question. Thanks!

Comment: 140 mA × (9 V − 5 V) = 0.56 W. The regulator can dissipate up to 0.6 W with the minimum pad size. Then, assuming the Arduino complies with this required minimum, you should be (barely) fine.

Comment: Thanks Everyone! That answers my question. Sorry for all the confusions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you have 3 LEDs ... call them A, B and C (the fact that they are a group of 14 LEDs is a red herring).  As a function of the distance measured, you want ONE of LED A, B or C lit.

Since you are using an Arduino, you have GPIO pins.  Connect a different GPIO to each of A, B and C.   You can then write an application that senses the distance (as measured by the HC-SR04) and depending on the distance returned, have a set of  "if" statements which will choose which of the GPIOs to set HIGH and the others LOW.  The GPIO set HIGH will switch on the corresponding LED.

In fact, its going to look a lot like this Instructable:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Arduino-and-HC-SR04-Example/

Comment: I think you are understanding. I was just concerned about running both the LEDs and the distance sensor off the 5v output. I didn't think it would matter as long as I always had one set of lights on so the sensor would have power

Comment: The main difference with the link you posted is the LED is being powered by the GPIO. I was under the impression that the GPIO pins wouldn't supply enough voltage (or current, I'm not sure... I really am just starting). Here is where I got the original schematic: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78096/power-14-red-leds-and-arduino-from-same-source#

Comment: The maximum amount of current through a GPIO pin is rated at 40mA.  If an LED sinks about 20mA then you can series wire 2 LEDs.  If you need to power more LEDs when a GPIO pin goes positive, then you have choices.  You can use a transistor or something like a 4050 IC (drive up to 6 higher current devices).  The maximum output current through an Arduino is 200mA ... so if you are to power everything from the Arduino, you need to ensure that you are less than this in total.

Comment: Which brings me back to the schematic above. The LEDs are powered via 5v connection, which if I have read everything correctly, can support greater current (900 mA) because it doesn't run through the Arduino

Comment: In the schematic, we see one GPIO controlling a bunch of LEDs which is not what I understand the plan to be.  The schematic also shows that the LEDs are being powered by the output 5V from the Arduino.  The Arduino spec says that it can source a max of 200mA.  Now, if you need 900mA then you connect a source that does NOT come from Arduino and give both the Arduino and the driving source a common ground.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, but everything I find says the GPIO pins are current limited, but the 5 v supports more. I just double checked http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno and it specifies a current limit for the 3.3 v but says nothing about the 5 v and other posts have suggested the 5 v. I am not sure how much I actually need, the LEDs in the set up above only draw about 140 mA according to the post linked. Essentially I planned on having three of those led chains each hooked up to their own transistor and GPIO pi and selecting a set based on readings from the distance sensor

Comment: Perhaps I have jumped too far into the deep end :-/

Comment: Please don't get discouraged ... the good folks on communities like this are here to help and before long, you too will be offering assistance.  Here is the official page on the specs of the Arduino.

http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoPinCurrentLimitations

It seems to be unambiguous that the Arduino can source a total of 200mA.  This is irrespective of the voltage pin used.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and encouragement. The link http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno says that there is a 5 v output straight from the board's voltage regulator. Is that not separate from the output pins?

Comment: @Kolban: The 200 mA figure you quote does _not_ relate to the Arduino's 5 V pin: it's the maximum current the ATmega328P can _sink_ on its Vcc pin. It's also the total current the Arduino can source on all its GPIO pins combined, plus the ATmega's own consumption.